# Override class in java

Tags: java, overriding, classloader

Assume I have a project **K**

**K** depends `lib.jar`

In `lib.jar` , there is a class named `x.y.z.Foo`

If i create the same class `x.y.z.Foo` in **K** , then in this project when I create a instance of `Foo` , now will JVM use `Foo` in **K** rather than in `lib.jar` ?

---

And if it's unstable or depends on something , how to make sure that `Foo` should use **K**'s version rather than `lib.jar`?

Comment: It depends on which one is first in the class path and where it is instantiated. You can look into custom classloaders to solve this.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to open a door to a world of pain, if not for yourself then for whoever may have to deal with your code afterwards.  You should either spend some quality time reading up on this, or think about using OSGi or something similar, even if just creating a mega-bundle.  If you decide to go your own way you should look into a similar well tread path to know what kind of unexpected bumps might await you (getting the right version in one spot may only be a small step).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994147/what-are-the-implications-of-having-duplicate-classes-in-java-jar/8994188#8994188

Comment: That's what [JAR Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell) is about.

Comment: Thanks all, and yes,that's may not be a graceful method ,  but i'm just looking for a solution to solve this problem

Comment: An alternative, more standard approach that just popped in to my head (inspired by recent personal experience) would be to use AOP weaving.

Comment: @MattWhipple that must be another hell.

Comment: @jackalope not if you take the time to work with it.  It's perfectly maintainable and robust if done properly, and it avoids the opacity that puts the hell in jar hell.  In this scenario it would be to also handle a wider range of modifications while mediating the risk of breaking existing client code which was compiled against the original version or is within another classloader.

Comment: @MattWhipple WOW, I'm sure that would be the hell of performance and mantainence. Tried AOP earlier.

Comment: @jackalope Runtime performance is not impacted at all with build/load time weaving and only marginally with proper runtime weaving.  Maintenance is largely what AOP is all about if done properly (even though this would not be its intended use, the maintainability wouldn't change).  Both of these evidenced by AOP's widespread use in lightweight frameworks like Spring. It's obviously not a viable answer from your perspective but could be considered by someone else looking at this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java class loading behaviour in a standalone application (at least with no custom classloaders) is stable. Make sure that your k.jar (or path) comes before lib.jar in `-cp` java arg

```
java -cp k.jar lib.jar ...
```

or add dependencies to /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF of your K project as

```
...
Class-Path: lib1.jar lib2.jar
...
```

and run

```
java -jar k.jar
```

k.jar classes will be loaded first

in Maven it is

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
         ...
```

Comment: How to do this with maven?

Comment: How to do this in Android?

Comment: How to do this with SBT?