# jar class file vs local class with same name and package

Tags: java, jar, package

I have a situation , I have jar files which contains
`com.somepackage.ABC.class` file
and I created in my local workspace `com.somepackage.ABC.java` (same name and package) rewrite existing functionality of `ABC.java` 
I am getting issue when I run my program it is always pickup jar ABC file
not my local.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the contents of the jar file?

Comment: How are you repacking the JAR? Try some tools like http://jd.benow.ca which will help you to do it easily

Comment: It's not recommended to have 2 versions of a class see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994147/what-are-the-implications-of-having-duplicate-classes-in-java-jar. Anyway what is your question ?

Comment: Hi Jean , same jar file has class which called ABC object as reference. I rewrite ABC class in my local , so I am trying to use new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As far as possible, you should remove the conflict in the package and name of the class. Simply use another class name (e.g. `DEF`) or another package name. There are ways to do this using mechanisms like [services](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html).

Assuming you must live with the conflict, your results, by default, are going to depend on the ClassPath with which the JVM is started. After you compile your local `ABC.java` to `ABC.class` in current folder (the actual class is in `com/somepackage`) then, you should give your classpath as: `java -cp ".:path/to/foo.jar` (on Unix) or `java -cp .;path\to\foo.jar` (on Windows), then your local class will take precedence over the the one in the JAR file.

Comment: As it might be silly question , where should I add  java -cp .;path\to\foo.jar. I am using tomcat 6

Comment: Oh, that was not apparent in your original question. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1301458/437506. In that case, instead of the leading '.', you will need to use the path (top folder) where your version of `ABC.class` resides.