# Another parent class causes exception in classloader

Tags: java

I have some class *B* loaded by classloader.
And I have my class *A* which extends class *B'*(its name and package path equals to one of B's but *B* and *B'* lay in different jars)

My question is , is it possible to classload class *A*? Or the exception would arise?(due to classes *B* and *B'* clash)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994147/what-are-the-implications-of-having-duplicate-classes-in-java-jar

Comment: *"I have some class `B` loaded by classloader"* All classes are loaded by a classloader. Are you saying that you have *multiple* independent classloaders? Are `B` and `B'` in the same classloader? If same classloader, then only one of them will be loaded, e.g. the one whose jar file is listed first in the classpath. If different classloaders, then they are different classes, even if they have the same FQN and even if its the same `.class` file from the same jar file, and are not assignment-compatible.

Comment: @Andreas same classloader. B' loaded first. B and A afterwards. And Class A extends B.

Comment: If B' and B have the same package and class name, i.e. the same FQN (Fully Qualified Name), then a single classloader wouldn't load them both, so what you just said cannot be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having multiple classes with the same name and package in multiple jar-s won't cause an exception to be thrown automatically.

And actually if the duplicate classes are identical, you won't have any problem.

If the classes are different, that can be a problem. In example, if the version of the class being loaded is missing a method that is present in the other version; and some client code tries to invoke the missing method, a `NoSuchMethodError` will be thrown.